# Question about inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V=C([-1, 1])$ and $$\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)dx$$
Let $W=\{f \in V \mid f\text{ is even}\}$. Find $W^\perp$.

**Progress:** I know that every odd function belongs to $W^\perp$ and I suspect $W^\perp=\{f \in V \mid f\text{ is odd}\}$.

Comment: The constant $0$ function is also in W perp.

Comment: Isn't 0 an odd function? let f=0, then f(-x)=-f(x)=0 for all x

Comment: The piece you're missing is that every function is the sum of an even and odd function.

Comment: @vinicius-rodrigues Yes, you are right. I suppose $0$ is both odd and even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g$ be an odd function. Then $fg$ is odd for all even functions $f$ in $C([-1, 1])$, therefore $\langle f, g\rangle=0$ for all $f \in C([-1, 1])$
Now suppose $g$ isn't odd. Let:
$$u(x)=\frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}$$ $$v(x)=\frac{g(x)-g(-x)}{2}$$
It's clear that $g=u+v$, $u$ is even and $v$ is odd. Since $g$ isn't even, $u\neq0$. Finally:
$$\langle u, g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 u(x)g(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1 u(x)v(x)dx+\int_{-1}^1 u(x)u(x)dx=0+\int_{-1}^1 u(x)^2dx>0$$
We have shown that $g \in W^\perp \Leftrightarrow g \text{ is odd}$.

Thanks to: vadim123

Comment: a simple typo: at the last line, $g$ is *odd*.